# Azure AD - Getting Update password screen instead of incorrect password message when using a specific old password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

For a specific user in Azure AD, say (xyz@mail.com), when I use a specific old password such as pass@321, it redirects me to the Update your password screen stating - **"You need to update your password because this is the first time you are signing in, or because your password has expired."**

While if I use the current correct password, it signs in successfully. Or if I use some other old password or some wrong password, it correctly shows the message **"Your account or password is incorrect. If you don't remember your password, reset it now."**

Is there a way to flush out old password history from Azure AD or to debug the old password properties?

I can't delete the user and create again as there is lot of dependency in my team on that user id(xyz@mail.com)

[image]

Comment: When you use specific old password , always get `You need to update your password because this is the first time you are signing in, or because your password has expired` message  even you set the new password in update password screen ?

Comment: Try to use another Internet Browser

Comment: @NanYu - Yes, even if I change the password through that screen, entering that password (pass@321) again goes to the update password screen.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT - I have tried in IE, EDGE and Chrome. It's the same behaviour everywhere.

Comment: Are you able to log in with the new password as well?

Comment: @Saca Yes I am able to login with the new password